# Is that possible that Mathematica can locate the maximum of a scalar function whereas Mathematica Alpha cannot?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I am trying to understand the difference between Mathematica that one installs in the laptop versus Mathematica Alpha on the web.  Specifically, I would like to learn how their computational powers differ in term of solving an optimization problem.

## Question

Is that possible that Mathematica can locate the maximum of a scalar function whereas Mathematica Alpha cannot?

For information, Mathematica is the computational product by Wolfram Research; Mathematica Alpha, if I understand correctly,  is the web demo version of Mathematica.

Comment: You could download [Mathematica trial free version](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/) and see the difference.

Comment: wolfram alpha (not "mathematica alpha") should not be thought of as a demo version of mathematica.  Alpha does not *generally* accept mathematica input syntax, so, time limitations aside, there are endless mathematica capability's that can not be performed by alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible that Mathematica will solve problems that Alpha cannot - or *will* not because of the time limits. The desktop product does not have any such limits.

From the [Wolfram|Alpha FAQs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/faqs4.html):

> **What are Wolfram|Alpha's main limitations?**
>
> [...] It limits the computation time for each query.
>
> **How much math can Wolfram|Alpha do?**
>
> Pretty much anything that's possible using today's best algorithms—subject only to the constraint that the computations must complete in the time Wolfram|Alpha has available.